# Hadoop FileSystem - How to delete all files that are of zero size in a given hdfs directory?

Tags: shell, hadoop, filesystems

I have a hdfs directory A in the path: /user/A

How do I delete all files within A that are of zero size?

Answer (score 4):

Deleting only files:

```
hdfs dfs -rm $(hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/A/ | grep -v "^d" | awk '{if ($5 == 0) print $8}')
```

Test what you get first, since there are lots of HDFS formats, that may have metadata or files with 0 byte sizes (like parquet ..SUCCESS, ..TEMPORARY etc.)

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/A/ | grep -v "^d" | awk '{if ($5 == 0) print $8}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpfull

`hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/to/directory/ | grep part- | awk '{ if ($5 == 0) print $8 }' | xargs hdfs dfs -rm`